# Hide menu item conditionally in Toolbar using DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-dialogfragment

I'm doing a mobile application in Android with JAVA using a DialogFragment with Toolbar.

I want to hide a menu item conditionally.

Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:title="favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_off_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:title="delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="save"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingStart="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- EditText's and buttons ..... -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

DialogFragment

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements Toolbar.OnClickListener, Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = "my_dialog";

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    public static MyDialogFragment display(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        NewPersonDialogFragment exampleDialog = new NewPersonDialogFragment();
        exampleDialog.show(fragmentManager, TAG);
        return exampleDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(NewPersonDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme_FullScreenDialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
            dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.AppTheme_Slide);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_new_person, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.new_person_dialog_menu);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(this);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        toolbar.setTitle("Add new");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // This is working fine
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // This is working fine
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_favorite:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_save:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        // Removing item doesn't work!
        menu.removeItem(R.id.action_delete);
    }

}
```

I open the DialogFragment like this:

```
MyDialogFragment.display(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

When I open the DialogFragment, the menu item is not hidden.

As other topics says, I have tried:

- `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onActivityCreated` method.
- `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method.

My goal is to hide/remove a menu item based on a condition when the user opens the DialogFragment.

Comment: You're inflating that menu directly yourself. It's not an options menu, so those methods won't help. Call `getMenu()` on your `Toolbar` to get the `Menu` object that you can modify.

Comment: @MikeM. I did `Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();` in `onViewCreated`, after `toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` and it's working. I can now hide items, thank you very much. If you want, add it as a solution and I will accept it.